# Cancan authorize custom module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have a custom module in my lib directory that I load in my Application controller. I started using cancan and now I am getting Access Denied error for all the actions in my custom module. I don't want cancan to check authorization on my custom module. One way to get around this is to use `except => [:action_name_in_my_custom_module]` but I have lot of actions that I use in my application at many places. I need a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a module of controller actions and you are including it in your controllers, is there a reason you didn't put them all in `ApplicationController`?

One thing you can try is using `skip_before_filter` in the module. This will call the method on any class in which you include MyModule:

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.class_eval <<-filters
      skip_before_filter :filter_method_to_skip, only: [:method_a, :method_b, ...]
    filters
  end
end


class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :filter_method
  include MyModule
end
```

I believe it needs to be included *after* your before filters are defined.